# helm chart will not expose ip address to ping localhost:port

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm

I am running minikube on MacOS, and want to expose the ip address and port for running this example helm chart -
https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/create-your-first-helm-chart/

I tried to ping the localhost:58064, but it wouldn't connect.

```
helm install --dry-run --debug ./mychart --set service.internalPort=8080
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '58064'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:58064"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] CHART PATH: /Users/me/Desktop/HelmTest/mychart

NAME:   messy-penguin
REVISION: 1
RELEASED: Tue Jun 12 17:56:41 2018
CHART: mychart-0.1.0
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
service:
  internalPort: 8080

COMPUTED VALUES:
affinity: {}
image:
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: nginx
  tag: stable
ingress:
  annotations: {}
  enabled: false
  hosts:
  - chart-example.local
  path: /
  tls: []
nodeSelector: {}
replicaCount: 1
resources: {}
service:
  internalPort: 8080
  port: 80
  type: ClusterIP
tolerations: []

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:

---
# Source: mychart/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: messy-penguin-mychart
  labels:
    app: mychart
    chart: mychart-0.1.0
    release: messy-penguin
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: mychart
    release: messy-penguin
---
# Source: mychart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: messy-penguin-mychart
  labels:
    app: mychart
    chart: mychart-0.1.0
    release: messy-penguin
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mychart
      release: messy-penguin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mychart
        release: messy-penguin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mychart
          image: "nginx:stable"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: http
          resources:
            {}
MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/HelmTest quantum-fusion$ curl 127.0.0.1:58064
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 58064: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `minikube` is from the docker-machine family, running `minikube ip` will output the IP address of the virtual machine, and **that** is the IP upon which you should attempt to contact your cluster, not localhost.

Furthermore, `[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '58064'` is **helm** making a tunnel to the embedded `tiller` Pod inside your cluster, and is not anything that you should be using at all. That's actually why it is prefixed with `[debug]`: because it is only useful for extreme circumstances.

Finally, you will need to use `kubectl port-forward` to reach your deployed Pod since the `Service` is using a `ClusterIP`, which as its name implies is only valid inside the cluster. You can also create a second `Service` of `type: NodePort` and it will allocate a TCP/IP port on the virtual machine's IP that routes to the `port:` of the `Service`. You *may* be able to inform your Helm chart to do that for you, depending on whether the author exposed that kind of decision through the chart's `values.yaml`.

The other "asterisk" to that `port-forward` versus `Service` of `type: NodePort` part is that I see in the output a mention of an `Ingress` resource for `chart-example.local`, but that pragmatically is only meaningful if you have a running "ingress controller," but if you do, then it *already* has a TCP/IP port upon which you should contact your cluster, just ensuring that you provide the connection with a `curl -H "host: chart-example.local" http://$(minikube ip):${the_ingress_port}` so that the ingress controller can route the request to the correct `Ingress`.